# mocha doesn't clean the environment between re-runs when watching

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

So I have noticed in the past that if I change some code inside callbacks when running `mocha --watch` the changes aren't picked up. I need to kill it and restart it.

This usually isn't a big problem.

However, I'm now managing some states in some callbacks (`sequelize hooks`) and my tests will always fail when running more than once. I keep `mocha --watching` my code as I write it, and it gets really annoying to restart it every time. Basically I can't use the `--watch` feature anymore because the old callbacks are running with stale state.

Is there a way to have it reload everything as new?

Comment: I've noticed this as well.  I was able to get it to clean up properly by manually importing { afterEach } and executing my cleanup function (in this case, exported from '@testing-library/react'), though this is not optimal.